# Custom Fields Pro : Remove $ symbol from output field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a site for a business. It is done in wordpress and uses advanced custom fields pro (plugin) to set prices for services. I didn't write the site!!! There is a custom field set that you enter a number and it shows '$ number' on the site. I need to change the number field to accept a text string. I figured that out. Problem is there is still a $ symbol that shows on the page (the control in acf for this isn't set. So I looked around. and found this string on a home.php page:

```
foreach ($singleservice as $row) {
                $info = $row['service_information'];
                $price = $row['service_price'];
                $price = '$'.$price;
                echo '<div class = "singleservice clearfix">
                    <div class = "text">'
                        .$info.
                    '</div><!--text-->
                    <div class = "price">'
                        .$price.
                    '</div><!--price-->
                </div><!--singleservice-->';
```

It has been awhile since I've done any coding and would have thought the coder set this in afc plugin. But can I just change the above line: $price = '$'.$price; >to> $price = $price; ? OR am I missing something with the plugin or something else. I don't want to break anything big!!!
I appreciate the help and knowledge here, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just have to remove the `'$'.` on `$price = '$'.$price;`

Edit:

Would look like this: `$price = $price;`

Doesn't seem to be text surrounding the ouput?
You may want to change output to:

```
<div class = "price">'
   $price
'</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I only need remove  " '$' not '$' . " It has been awhile since I've coded and no experience with php. But I thought it would need to be changed to $price = $price  | not | $price = .$price

Comment: You're correct.  You can remove the `'$'.`   The period is there to concatenate the dollar sign onto the value of the variable.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. When I get the chance to try that - I'll let you know how it works. I didn't want to break the site fiddling with fixes (minimize downtime). By the way are you familiar with 'advanced custom fields' for wordpress, do you know if you can alter this in specific fields. IE: this process lists about 8 prices for various services. without altering the code can I just remove the $ symbol for 3 of those fields, is there a control like that?

Comment: Sorry, I've never actually used that plugin, but I would think that would be an option .  It seems like that field is specific for a currency value, but if you wanted a standard text field, I would think you could replace the current field...again, not too familiar with the plugin.

Comment: As soon as I get ftp access to change the files permissions I'll try the change.

Comment: I'm going to have time and access later this morning (I think) something like this would be better for me is this correct to try. if( $price !== 0 ){ 
$price = '$' . $price; 
} 
else { 
$price = 'Call for Price'; 
}

Comment: Excellent!  Glad I could help!  If you could mark my answer as correct that would be much appreciated.  Happy Coding! : )